# C sockets download function transfering corrupt files

Tags: c, sockets, download

I am trying to implement download in C sockets. The idea is to get the size of the file in the client and send 1024 bytes at once, multiple times, then send the remainder of the bytes. On the server side you will receive these bytes, and append them to a file created on the run.

**This is the client code.**

```
char localfilename[260];
if (get_string_between_spaces(localfilename, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, 2) == -1)   {
    /*
    the function above goes through the buffer where a command is stored , like "download hi.txt hello.txt and stores into localfilename "hi.txt"
    */
    send_message(sock, "error", sizeof("error")); //this function is a wrapper for send()
    goto jump;
}
FILE *pLOCALFILE;
pLOCALFILE = fopen(localfilename, "rb");
if (!pLOCALFILE) {
    send_message(sock, "File not found on target system.Exiting..\n", sizeof("File not found on target system.Exiting..\n"));
    goto jump;
} else {
    send_message(sock, "File found target system going on...\n", sizeof("File found target system going on...\n"));
}
int size_of_file = get_file_size(pLOCALFILE); //returns the size of the file
int remainder = size_of_file % 1024; 
int quotient = size_of_file / 1024;

send_integer(sock, size_of_file);
send_integer(sock, remainder);
send_integer(sock, quotient);
for (int i = 0; i < quotient; i++) {
    /*
     you will want to send 1024 bytes for quotient times 
    */
    fread(container, 1, 1024, pLOCALFILE);
    send(sock, container, sizeof(container) , 0);
    memset(container, 0, sizeof(container));
}
//send over the remaining bytes
//if quotient == 0 the for loop doesn't get executed , the file transfer being done in one send() instruction
fread(container, 1, remainder, pLOCALFILE);
send(sock, container, remainder, 0);
memset(container, 0, sizeof(container));
fclose(pLOCALFILE);
```

**This is the server code.**

```
char filename[260];
get_string_between_spaces(filename, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 2, 3);
/*
    the function above goes through the buffer 
where a command is stored , like "download hi.txt 
hello.txt and stores into localfilename "hello.txt"
*/
FILE *pFILETOWRITE;
pFILETOWRITE = fopen(filename, "ab");//open the file in append bytes mode
if (pFILETOWRITE) {
    printf("The file %s has been opened.\n", filename);
} else {
    printf("Couldn't open the %s file.\n", filename);
    goto jump;
}
            
recv(client_socket, receive_response, sizeof(receive_response), 0);
printf("%s\n", receive_response);
//the receive response above receives the ok to continue if we were able to open the file on the client
char containerOFmode[1024];
bzero(containerOFmode, sizeof(containerOFmode));
int size_of_client_file = recv_integer(client_socket);
int remainder = recv_integer(client_socket);
int quotient= recv_integer(client_socket);
int bytes_transferred = 0;
printf("%d bytes are to be transferred.\n", size_of_client_file);
printf("The remainder is %d\n", remainder);
printf("The cat is %d\n", quotient);
//receive and print the size of the file , the quotient and the remainder           
for (int i = 0; i < quotient; i++) {
    recv(client_socket, containerOFmode, sizeof(containerOFmode), 0);
    bytes_transferred += sizeof(containerOFmode);
    fwrite(containerOFmode, sizeof(char), sizeof(containerOFmode), pFILETOWRITE);
    printf("%s\n", containerOFmode);
    printf("The size of this send was:%d\n", sizeof(containerOFmode));
    printf("Bytes transferred so far:%d\n", bytes_transferred);
    bzero(containerOFmode, sizeof(containerOFmode));
    /*
        for each iteration receive the 1024 bytes and write it to the pFILETOWRITE , while also being verbose to the console
    */
}
recv(client_socket, containerOFmode, remainder. 0);
bytes_transferred += remainder;
fwrite(containerOFmode, sizeof(char), remainder, pFILETOWRITE);
printf("%s\n", containerOFmode);
printf("The size of this send was:%d\n", remainder);
printf("Bytes transferred so far:%d\n", bytes_transferred);
bzero(containerOFmode, sizeof(containerOFmode));
/*
        receive the remaining bytes and write it to the pFILETOWRITE , while also being verbose to the console
*/
fclose(pFILETOWRITE);
goto jump;//
```

The problem is that for large files, more than 10 MB or so, videos or executables become corrupt. I don't know why this happens, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every beginner tutorial explains why you must check the return value of recv.

Comment: The short answer is that `bytes_transferred += sizeof(containerOFmode);` assumes it receives a full buffer every time, which will not always be true.  You must use the return value from `recv` to know how many bytes were actually received (or if there was an error).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is you assume `send()` and `recv()` always succeed and send and/or receive the total number of bytes requested. This is incorrect: you must check the return values of these functions and act accordingly.

There are other issues, but you did not post a compilable program so much of the code is missing for a more complete analysis.